# cronjob not working

Tags: cron

I have a strange problem. I have a cron set up to check a database for a given date that is entered. If today's date matches the db recond, it supposed to change a value in a db table.

now, for some reason if the cron is set to go off every minute, it works like a charm. If it's set to a certain time, it doesn't fire at all.
(MYDOMAIN is set to the proper domain. )

works with: 
* * * * * php -q /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN.com/httpdocs/admin/scripts/includes/check_date.php

doesn't work with: 
40 16 * * * php -q /var/www/vhosts/MYDOMAIN.com/httpdocs/admin/scripts/includes/check_date.php

or any variation of that time

any idea why it wont fire on anything else then every minute?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check that your system time matches the timezone you are expect it to fire in by running

```
date
```

Comment: It matches exactly. Right down to the second.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `59 23 * * *` ?  try the last minute of the day.  Maybe the script only works late in the day ...